# Associating conditional statements with buttons rendering in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to associate a few conditions with buttons in React. Here is the code:

```
class Stopwatch extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.clickstart=this.clickstart.bind(this);
        this.clickreset=this.clickreset.bind(this);
        this.clickstop=this.clickstop.bind(this);
        this.state={
          timer:0
        }

    }
    clickstart(){
         this.incrementer=setInterval( ()=>this.setState({
             timer:this.state.timer+1
         }),1000);
    }
    clickreset(){
        clearInterval(this.incrementer);// note what we did here 
        this.setState({
            timer:0
        })
    }
    clickstop(){
      clearInterval(this.incrementer);
    }

    render(){

        return(
            <div className="stopwatch">
            <h1>{convertfun(this.state.timer)}</h1>
            <button  onClick={this.clickstart}>Start</button>
            <button onClick={this.clickreset}>Reset</button>
            <button onClick={this.clickstop}>Stop</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

I want the start button to be functional only if the `timer` reads zero or it's value is zero. How do I achieve this in React?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Stopwatch extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.clickstart=this.clickstart.bind(this);
        this.clickreset=this.clickreset.bind(this);
        this.clickstop=this.clickstop.bind(this);
        this.state={
          timer:0
        }

    }

    clickstart() {
         this.incrementer=setInterval( ()=>this.setState({
             timer:this.state.timer+1
         }),1000);
    }

    clickreset() {
        clearInterval(this.incrementer);// note what we did here 
        this.setState({
            timer:0
        })
    }

    clickstop() {
      clearInterval(this.incrementer);
    }

    render() {

        return(
            <div className="stopwatch">
            <h1>{convertfun(this.state.timer)}</h1>
            // Change here
            {this.state.timer == 0 && <button  onClick={this.clickstart}>Start</button>}
            <button onClick={this.clickreset}>Reset</button>
            <button onClick={this.clickstop}>Stop</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like:

```
 return(
         <div className="stopwatch">
         <h1>{convertfun(this.state.timer)}</h1>
         {this.state.timer == 0 && <button  onClick={this.clickstart}>Start</button>}
         <button onClick={this.clickreset}>Reset</button>
         <button onClick={this.clickstop}>Stop</button>
         </div>
        );
```

Or

```
 render(){

       let button = null;
       if(this.state.timer == 0) button = <button onClick={this.clickstart}>Start</button>;

        return(
            <div className="stopwatch">
            <h1>{convertfun(this.state.timer)}</h1>
            {button}
            <button onClick={this.clickreset}>Reset</button>
            <button onClick={this.clickstop}>Stop</button>

            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: yes, this works fine.Can you give few more examples as how I handle complicated cases or link me to something to read more about this?

Comment: @satyajeetjha if it helped, you can accept the answer; here is some info: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html.

Answer (score 0):

you can add disabled attribute to button with condition

```
<button disabled={this.state.timer === 0} onClick={this.clickstart}>Start</button>
```